# Regenerate Azure IoT Edge hub certificate

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I created a VM in Azure with the name myedgeserver and installed the IoT Edge runtime on it. Afterwards I created a dns name for the server, resulting in the name myedgeserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.

When installing the server it creates a self-signed certificate with the name of the host, i.e. myedgeserver.

When connecting to the edge server with the fqdn (on port 8883 mqtt) it returns this certificate, which generates an error on the client since the client expects a certificate with the fqdn.

I changed the hostname in /etc/aziot/config.toml and ran

`sudo iotedge config apply`

but I'm still getting the certificate with only the vm name.

How can I regenerate this self-signed certificate on the edge server using the fqdn?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to regenerate the certificates and use them instead for IoT Hib and your edge device (your VM). Follow the below link to generate the certificates as outlined in the article.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-edge/how-to-create-test-certificates.md